# PickerView: how to center horizontally and no space?

Tags: swiftui

i have this code.

unfortunately the pickerview is not centered horizontally and there is too much space between the buttons and the pickerview (vertically), i now i can use offset, but is there a better way?

```
   var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Hi"), content: {
                    Button("Alphabet") {
                    }.frame(alignment: .center)
                    Button("Ok") {
                    }.frame(alignment: .center)
                    HStack {
                        Picker(selection: $sortedBy,
                               label: Text(""),
                               content: {
                                ForEach(p, id: \.self) { category in
                                    Text(category)
                                }
                            }).pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

@Reiner Fischer...here is the result of your proposol (unfortunately not centered)

[image]

Comment: Actually the picker itself is centered (I've added screenshot), but its internal content is not. Looks like a picker's defect.

Comment: fascinating..... :D

Answer (score -1):

The problem is your empty label

```
 label: Text(""),
```

even if the label is empty it takes some space on the left side of the picker. You can check by just adding some text to the label.

To get rid of the label, adjust your code like this:

```
.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
.labelsHidden()
```

That will center your picker selections

Update 21.02.2020

Hi Chris, enclosed is the code, i tested and that centers the picker:

```
struct PickerView: View {

let p:[Vital] = [
    .init(name: "0"),
    .init(name: "1"),
    .init(name: "2"),
    .init(name: "3")
]

@State private var sortedby = 0

var body: some View {

        Picker(selection: $sortedby, label: Text("")) {
            ForEach(p) { post in
               Text(post.name)
            }
        }.pickerStyle(DefaultPickerStyle())
         .labelsHidden()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: i just tested your solution...and it is still not centered....i added a picture for your soltuion....

Comment: Hi Chris, strange. I have enclosed the code, i tested